# Django make the object create only once per 24 hours

Tags: python, django

Here is my Django model:

```py
class mymodel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

How can I make the object created only once per 24 hours?
I know it's possible to do with `unique_for_date` but cannot understand how
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#unique-for-date

Also, I want to show an error if the user wanted to create more than once per 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique_for_date` only works in the case of ModelForm. Also, If this field is listed in `excluded`, it will skip validation.
As per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#unique-for-date)

> This is enforced by Model.validate_unique() during model validation
> but not at the database level. If any unique_for_date constraint
> involves fields that are not part of a ModelForm (for example, if one
> of the fields is listed in exclude or has editable=False),
> Model.validate_unique() will skip validation for that particular
> constraint.

You need another field that will be unique by created_at like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Add this field
    my_field = models.CharField(unique_for_date='created_at')
    
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**As you are using DateTimeField for created_at, only the date portion of this field will be considered.**

I'd suggest overriding the save method of your model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            date_from = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            MyModel.objects.get(created_at__gte=date_from)
            # raise some save error
        except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
            super(MyModel,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks but what's the solution with the 'unique_for_date'? 
I prefer to don't use save method

Comment: For that, you just need to add another field. I also updated my answer.

Comment: Regarding the first solution, is this considering days? because the full date should not be unique. Just days should be unique.

Comment: Yes, time will be ignored from the full date.